# time.localtime() question beginner python

Tags: python, datetime

I'm having a syntax error on the second line of this code, I'm trying to make a counter with the winsound beep.

I think the problem is with the format() part, but i get a highlighted =, equals sign when i try to run the program. syntax error

```
def print_time(secs):
  print('{0}:{1:02}'.format(secs//60,secs%60),end=' ')
  print("left to wait...")
```

This is my second week programming, very basic understanding of comp sci or of languages.

This looks like a wonderful site to learn from.

If the part of the code I wrote looks fine, i can post the rest of it up as well to help find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're reading documentation for Python 3.x, but running Python 2.x. Try this instead:

```
def print_time(secs):
  print '{0}:{1:02}'.format(secs//60,secs%60),
  print "left to wait..."
```

Also, [`divmod()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#divmod).

Comment: Thank you very much for labeling the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_time(secs):
    print '{0}:{1:02}'.format(secs//60,secs%60),
    print "left to wait..."
```

The above code should work fine.

Python 3+ treats 'print' as a function and hence introduces end=' ' to suppress newline. But, in earlier versions of python it was done by appending ,(comma) to the print statement. See this link for [what's new in Python 3+](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html).

Apparently, your Python environment is 2.x and hence you are seeing the error.